# Узнать URL сайта с помощью js

Tags: javascript, url

Допустим скрипт заходит на страницу, и должен в консоль вывести URL. Как и с помощью чего это можно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Какой скрипт и каким образом заходит на страницу?

Comment: С помощью гугл расширения Tampermonkey я пишу скрипт для выполнения определенных действий на сайтах. И понадобилось узнать URL

Comment: Если это происходит внутри браузера, то может быть простой `window.location.href` будет работать?

Comment: m = windows.location.href;
    alert (m); так ?

Comment: Ну например :) Как это выводиться должно я не знаю уже )

Comment: хорошо, спасибо ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
export class UrlParser {
  constructor(url) {
    this.el = document.createElement('a');
    this.el.href = url === undefined ? window.location.href : url;
    this.href = this.el.href;
    this.protocol = this.el.protocol;
    this.hostname = this.el.hostname;
    this.port = this.el.port;
    this.pathname = this.el.pathname;
    this.search = this.el.search;
    this.hash = this.el.hash;
  }

  parsePathname() {
    const result = this.pathname
      .substr(1)
      .split('/')
      .filter(item => item.length > 0);
    return result.length > 0 ? result : null;
  }

  parseSearch() {
    const result = this.search
      .substr(1)
      .split('&')
      .filter(item => item.length > 0);
    if (result.length > 0) {
      const obj = {};
      result.forEach(element => {
        const parse = element.split('=');
        obj[parse[0]] = parse[1];
      });
      return obj;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```